# ethereum.setSelectedProvider is not a function?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, metamask

How to just open MetaMask no matter browser has installed how many wallet ?

I try the code but shows the error

> ethereum.setSelectedProvider is not a function

```
const activateInjectedProvider = (providerName: 'MetaMask' | 'CoinBase') => {
        const { ethereum } = window;

        if (!ethereum?.providers) {
            return undefined;
        }

        let provider;
        switch (providerName) {
            case 'CoinBase':
                provider = ethereum.providers.find(({ isCoinbaseWallet }: any) => isCoinbaseWallet);
                break;
            case 'MetaMask':
                provider = ethereum.providers.find(({ isMetaMask }: any) => isMetaMask);
                break;
        }

        if (provider) {
            ethereum.setSelectedProvider(provider);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        activateInjectedProvider('MetaMask');
    }, []);
```

For example real website for MetaMask button:
https://opensea.io/

[image]

Comment: "How to just open MetaMask no matter browser has installed how many wallet ?" Can you please clarify what this sentence is supposed to ask? It's not grammatically correct English, and therefore is not parse-able at the moment.

Comment: Sure, I update some infomation for my question.

Comment: I don't see any changes to the invalid sentence I referenced. To be clear, it's the first sentence in your post that needs clarifying, since that appears to be your actual question.

Comment: For example, My chrome browser had installed Phantom wallet and MetaMask wallet, when I trigger the function I try before `ethereum
  .request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })`, It will popup the window that includes Phantom and MetaMask. I want the popup just show MetaMask.  I try the function `ethereum.setSelectedProvider(provider);` is not working.